# Questions that ask for you to e-mail them to get the code

Tags: discussion, site-policy, asking-questions

What is the appropriate way to handle a question that doesn't post the code to review, but posts an e-mail address that you can I assume e-mail and get the code?

A (now-deleted) example is:

[Automatic craigslist poster, works but I am afraid the threads are not written properly.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/21341/21408)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's clearly not following the FAQ. Code must be posted in the question to be on-topic here. If the poster doesn't rectify it, the question will be closed as off-topic.