# Code review of YouTube video

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, third-party, hyperlinks

I have a [YouTube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnMF9In69aCVjJKg1UmtxXTh4NjTeGK-M) that I have created showing my iterative approach on a subject ("C# CUSTOM Script Language Creation").

I know that sites like this one have some limitations as to what is acceptable as far as a valid "question" is concerned, but I was wondering if anyone could give me some tips as to how I could get positive feedback on the work that I have done within the videos, as it was very iterative and lengthy, and seemingly impractical to fit into a site like this.

I really would like the feedback on this work though, and any suggestions as to how to make this work for Code Review is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions on Code Review must have the code in the post.

- [Can I put my code on a third party site and link to the site in my question?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308)
- [Reviews of code not stored here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/134)
- [Can I ask for a review on a website?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/215)
- [Questions that ask for you to e-mail them to get the code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/661)

---

If you want reviews of each video:

- Post the relevant *final* code from the video you want reviewed. You can post all of the *final* code if you want. (It should fit in a question)
- Don't post all of your questions at the same time. If you do it'd be a waste to review "Intro" when we can just review "stage 3".

  I'd recommend waiting a day after you get an answer.
- After you post a review for each section, make similar changes to the rest of your code. This means you should get better feedback, rather than us harass you with the same stuff.

  If you disagree with something we suggest, say so in the question so it's less likely anyone comments on it.

---

I can't really see any other problem you could have.

---

Additional posts that can help you post a good question and series of questions:

- [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436)
- [Simon's guide for asking a good question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429)
- [For an iterative review, is it okay to edit my own question to include revised code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1763)
- [How can I make my question get more attention?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6822)

Comment: This clarified my comment to Mast.

Answer (score 3):

Videos are no substitute for actual code.

However, if the code is included in the question and the question complies to the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I don't see a problem.

Comment: Great, that helps. So as far as questions relating to its review, should I just include the code, slap the Youtube link in-line stating that the context is within the links if it interests the reviewers, and move on?